# Segmentation fault with strcpy, even though pointers have pointee

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
void trim(char *line)
{
    int i = 0;
    char new_line[strlen(line)];
    char *start_line = line;
    while (*line != '\0')
    {
        if (*line != ' ' && *line != '\t')
        {
            new_line[i] = *line;
            i++;
        }
        line++;
    }
    new_line[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", start_line);
    printf("%s\n", new_line);
    strcpy(start_line, new_line);
}
```

I really cannot find the problem here. My pointers are initialized, and I made a pointer to have the start of the string line. At the end I would like to copy the new line in the old one, so the caller has a changed value of his line.

But strcpy() makes a segmentation fault. What is wrong?

This is the code that calls trim():

```
char *str = "Irish People Try American Food";
printf("%s\n", str);
trim(str);
printf("%s\n", str);
```

Comment: What if `line` doesn't contain a `' '` or a `'\t'`? Your `new_line[i] = '\0';` will evaluate to `new_line[strlen(line)] = '\0';`, which is UB.

Comment: `new_line[strlen(line)];` --> `new_line[strlen(line) + 1];`

Comment: Post the code that calls `trim(char *line)`.  Is it doing something  like `trim("  Test  ");`?

Comment: @chux It is updated now.

Comment: Code is attempting to modify a string literal `"Irish People Try American Food"`. --> UB.  (Many duplicates)

Comment: See my answer, now that you posted the code change `char *str = ` to `char str[100] =` to apply it to your test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to show the whole program; what calls "trim()"? Paul R's answer is right, you are one character short and it should be at least:

```
char new_line[strlen(line) + 1];
```

However, this will not always cause a segfault, and if it did it would probably not be at `strcpy()`.

The likely reason `strcpy(start_line, new_line)` is faulting is that start_line points to the original value of `line`. It is likely that you are calling the function like:

```
int main() {
    trim("blah blah\tblah");
    return 0;
}
```

If so, `line` is a pointer to a **constant** char array that can't be modified. On many OS's this is stored in a read-only memory area, so it will cause an immediate segmentation fault if a write attempt is made. So `strcpy()` then faults when trying to write into to this read only location.

As a quick test try this:

```
int main() {
    char test[100] = "blah blah\tblah";
    trim(test);
    return 0;
}
```

If it works, that's your specific issue with strcpy() faulting.

**EDIT** - the question was updated later to include the main() calling function, which confirmed that the trim function was called with a pointer to a string constant. The problem line is:

```
char *str = "Irish People Try American Food";
```

This creates a string literal, an array of 31 characters including a null terminator which cannot be modified. The pointer `str` is then initialized with the address of this *constant*, array.

The correction is to allocate a regular array of characters and then *initialize* it with the known string. In this case the assignment and temporary constant string literal may or may not be optimized out, but the end result is always the same - a writable array of characters initialized with the desired text:

```
char str[100] = "Irish People Try American Food";
/* or */
char str2[] = "American People Like Irish Beer";
/* or */
char *str3[37];
strcpy(str3, "And German Beer"); /* example only, need to check length */
```

These create normal writable char arrays of lengths 100, 32, and 37, respectively. Each is then initialized with the given strings.

The ANSI/ISO C standard defined the language such that a string literal is a array of `char` *that cannot be modified*. This is the case even as it was first standardized in C89. Prior to this string literals had been commonly writable, such as in the pre-standard K&R C of very early UNIX code.

> Identical string literals of either form need not be distinct.  If
>   the program attempts to modify a string literal of either form, the
>   behavior is undefined. - ANSI X3.159-1989

Many C89 and newer compilers have since then placed this array into the .text or .rodata segments where it may even be physically unwritable (ROM, read-only MMU pages, etc.), as discovered here. Compilers may also coalesce duplicate string constants into single one to conserve space - and you wouldn't to write into "one" of those either!

The fact that these semantically unwritable strings were still left as type `char *`, and that they could be assigned to and passed as such was known to be a compromise, even as the C89 standard was being drafted. That they did not use the then-brand-new type qualifier `const` was described as a **"not-completely-happy result"**. See [Richie's (DMR's)](http://yarchive.net/comp/string_literals.html) explanation.

And apparently that result still boomerangs around and whacks people upside the head nearly 30 years later.

Comment: So the problem was that I used `char *test;` instead of `char test[100];`. Why is the first one a constant?

Comment: @DennisvonEich I updated the answer. Basically because of history. Just another dusty corner. Fun stuff, though.

Comment: I am rather supprised that this topic is so complex.

Answer (score 6):

Your `new_line` string is one char too small - it does not have room for the final `'\0'` terminator - change:

```
char new_line[strlen(line)];
```

to:

```
char new_line[strlen(line) + 1];
```

You should also be aware that string literals can not be modified, so if you try to call your function like this:

```
trim("Hello world!");
```

then this will result in undefined behaviour. (You should also get a compiler warning if you try to do this.)

Comment: Thanks but on mos cases, the string have spaces and \t which means that it is smaller than the `char *line` parameter. I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: @DennisvonEich: well it's a bug that needs to be fixed - there may well be other bugs too.

Answer (score 4):

As @PaulR stated, your new line's buffer is too small. But instead of using another buffer that takes up more space, you could use a single-character approach, like this:

```
void trim(char *s)
{
    char *src = s, *dest = s;
    while (*src)
    {
        if ((*src != ' ') && (*src != '\t'))
            *dest++ = *src;
        ++src;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}
```